# How to make a background image with linear gradient responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a background image that has a URL referencing my image and a linear gradient. On desktop it is perfect, but obviously, when I change the screen size, the image itself does not change size. How can I make this responsive?

```
.image.filtered:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../../images/logo_color.png),
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(164, 128, 255, 0.25),
      rgba(255, 143, 131, 0.25)
    );
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: center left, left, right;
}
```

```
<div class="image filtered" data-position="center"></div>
```

Desktop view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPeSV.jpg

Mobile Size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnlh6.png

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set the `background-size` to `cover`. Only if your .image.filtered has a defined width and height.

````
.image.filtered:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../../images/logo_color.png),
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(164, 128, 255, 0.25),
      rgba(255, 143, 131, 0.25)
    );
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: center left, left, right;
  background-size: cover;
}```
````

Comment: Yeah, if I do that then the URL image gets blown up past the boundaries of the block. I was trying to figure out if there was a way to set the background Image specifically to a different size, but I haven't had much success.